# Best Android Device for 3d Development

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

Im planning to port my iPhone Game to Android, since the Android Simulator does not support GLES v2, I need to purchase a device to port the game.

What Im looking for is a device that have the following:

Android v2.3.x OS

Graphic Chipset (from Imagination Technologies)

Any suggestions?

Also I would like to know how it work developing for Android, is it similar as for iOS? plug the device through USB then from Eclipse with the Android SDK and NDK then launch and debug? Or is there other step that have to be done to be able to develop and debug directly on the device?

Tks in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

> Also I would like to know how it work developing for Android, is it similar as for iOS? plug the device through USB then from Eclipse with the Android SDK and NDK then launch and debug? Or is there other step that have to be done to be able to develop and debug directly on the device?

You can just press "Run" in Eclipse and your app will be uploaded to your device and start running. You can even debug on the running device itself. Yes you heard right. You can debug off the tablet you just plugged in.

> Any suggestions?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab (7 inch Froyo version) and it works great for me. My advice would be to buy the oldest piece of hardware that you plan to support so that you always know that it will work for everything.

P.S. This question may have been [better asked here](https://android.stackexchange.com/) but its on the line. I'm voting to leave it on Stack Overflow by not voting at all.